# Let $S$ be a subset of the metric space E. Let $S^{*}$ denote the closure of S.

Tags: real-analysis

Show that $S^{*} \supset S$, and $S$ is closed iff $S^{*} = S$

From what I understand, $S^{*}$ (the closure of a subset S) is the smallest closed set containing S and it is also the intersection of all closed sets containing  A.

How do I apply this definition to prove the first part? Namely that $S^{*} \supset S$

Also for the second part, in in order to show that $S$ is closed, I know I need to show that $S^{c}$ is open, but I am stuck on how to go about it.

Comment: You read carefully the word "containing" in the definition of the closure.

Answer (score 1):

As it is mentioned in the comments, basically the second sentencce of your question (i.e. the definition of closure) answers both questions.

1. By the very definition, $S^*$ is the smallest closed set *containing* $S$. So it contains $S$. By that we mean $S^*\supseteq S$.
2. We don't need complements here: if $S$ is closed, then it will be the smallest closed set containing itself. Conversely, if $S=S^*$ then $S$ is closed as $S^*$ is so, by the very definition.